# Creating a bar chart in R from data in a file

Tags: r, vector, sum, bar-chart

First I have created two `vectors` and put them together

`Vectors`: VektorLHI and VektorRHI

`sumLHIundRHI<-rbind2(VektorLHI,VektorRHI)`

Then I got:

[image: data]

Then I created:

[image: Barplot from my File]

with the command:

```
barplot(sumLHIundRHI[,-1])
```

But when I try to set `beside=TRUE`, I get an error

```
barplot(sumLHIundRHI[,-1], beside=TRUE)
Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary Operator
```

How is it correct?

Comment: for each column (except "infact") there should be two pillars, with the distinction between Infact = L and Infakt = R

Comment: Could you share a reproducible code with data?(https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please share `head` of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have shared data into a reproducible way:

```
sumLHIundRHI_reduced <- data.frame(Infarkt=c("L","R"),
           AG=c(2,5),
           PG=c(4,0),
           pP=c(3,3))
```

I think the problem is the structure of your data. In particular the first column of your dataset, because `barplot` function needs a vector or a matrix of values, and your data seems to be a dataframe:

```
data_ordered <- as.matrix(sumLHIundRHI_reduced[,2:4])
row.names(data_ordered) <- levels(sumLHIundRHI_reduced$Infarkt)
```

Now the function will work properly:

```
barplot(data_ordered, main="Your Plot",
        xlab="Number of ???", col=c("darkblue","red"),
        legend = rownames(data_ordered),beside=TRUE)
```

[image]